# Estimating intervals to equations analytically

Tags: calculus, derivatives, self-learning, numerical-calculus, interval-arithmetic

It's been a while I have had calculus, currently revising some numerical analysis.

I am asked to find, using Calculus, intervals containing solutions to the following equation:

$$ 2x\cos(2x) - (x+1)^2 = 0 $$

This exercises are in the context of Calculus Review which covered:

-Limits and Continuity

-Differentiability (Mean Value Theorem, Rolle's Theorem, Extreme Value Theorem)

-Integration

-Taylor Series and Polynomials

I am not sure how to systematically tackle this question. 
Thanks in advance.